# I'm getting unexpected behavior from my React Native handler/onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onpress

This is my state section..

```
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState('');
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
    const [locked, setLocked] = useState(true);
    const initialData = serverData.map((item) => ({ ...item, edited: false }));
    const [data, setData] = useState([...serverData]);
```

These are my handlers, the handlers in question are the edit text focused ones..

```
const handleLockPress = () => {
        setLocked(!locked);
    };

    const handleDeletePress = (item) => {
        const updatedData = data.filter((dataItem) => dataItem.id !== item.id);
        setData(updatedData);
    };

    const beginEditItem = (item) => {
        if (!locked) {
            setEditMode(true);
            setEditedText(item.textContent);
            setData((updatedData) =>
                updatedData.map((item) => (item.id === item.id ? { ...item, edited: true } : item))
            );
        }
    };

    const endEditItem = (item) => {
        if (!locked) {
            setEditMode(false);
            const updatedData = data.map((dataItem) =>
                dataItem.id === item.id ? { ...dataItem, edited: false, textContent: editedText } : dataItem
            );
            setData(updatedData);
        }
    };

    const handleTextChange = (itemId, text) => {
        setData((prevData) =>
            prevData.map((item) =>
                item.id === itemId ? { ...item, textContent: text, edited: true } : item
            )
        );
    };
```

And here is the view/car/container that contains the feature.

```
<View style={styles.cardContainer} >
    {data.map((item) => (
        < Card key={item.id} style={styles.card} onPress={() => { }}>
            <BlurView intensity={3}>
                <View style={styles.cardContent}>
                    <Card.Cover
                        source={item.image}
                        style={{
                            width: item.imageWidth,
                            height: item.imageHeight,
                            margin: 16,
                        }}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        {item.edited ? (
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.textText}
                                value={item.textContent}
                                onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(item.id, text)}
                                multiline
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Caption style={styles.textText} editable={!locked}>
                                {item.textContent}
                            </Caption>
                        )}
                        {/* <Caption style={styles.textText}>Nam quis nulla. Integer malesuada. In in enim a arcu imperdiet malesuada. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio urna, tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Phasellus rhoncus. ...</Caption> */}
                        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                            <View style={{ flex: 0 }} />
                            <View style={{ flex: 10, flexDirection: "row" }}>

                                <IconButton icon={locked ? 'lock-outline' : 'lock-open-outline'} iconColor='white' onPress={handleLockPress} />
                                {locked ? (
                                    <View />
                                ) : (
                                    <View style={styles.deleteEditContainer}>
                                        <IconButton icon="delete" iconColor="white" onPress={() => handleDeletePress(item)} />
                                        <IconButton icon={editMode ? 'plus' : 'pencil'} iconColor="white" onPress={() => (editMode ? endEditItem(item) : beginEditItem(item))} />
                                    </View>
                                )}
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </BlurView>
        </Card>
    ))}
</View>
```

I need each card to become editable once I have unlocked the card and then pressed the edit icon, then I need to edit the text that is already there, then save it by pressing the plus icon that the edit icon turns into..

Currently the edited text just goes away when I press the plus(save) icon, and isn't saved. I've been messing with it all morning, and at one point I had it so that it would save, but the edit existed in all cards, not just the one I was editing.. and right now, selecting edit makes all cards editable.

I feel like I've tangled myself up in this problem and cannot untangle myself easily. I need a rescue.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks like you have a logic error that has nothing to do with React or React Native. Try to write simple code in Vanilla JavaScript and try to reproduce the issue on platform like CodePen or JSFiddle that you can link with the question. I can't help you because I have no idea what exactly you try to do. Your lock is true and edit is false, so looking at the code you show everything should be read-only and don't allow for any interaction.

Comment: The image/text card starts locked.. to edit the text, the user has to unlock it, at which point the delete and edit icons are displayed.. then the user has to press the edit button, which turns into a plus sign that saves the edit when pressed. The edit state starts false because they shouldn't be able to edit until they have unlocked the accidental action protection and pressed edit.
I tried to create both jsfiddle and codepen, neither liked my code.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't notice handleLockPress on IconButton. You have really long lines. It's good practice to put your lines 120 characters max, a lot of people even enforce 80 characters for historical reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll try to change VSCode settings to 80 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you don't change this state at all during editing.

```js
const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState('');
```

You change this state when you begin editing, and you reset it when end editing.

on `handleTextChange` inside textInput you update the date directly but then you discard it with `editedText`.

To fix this you need to change:

```js
const handleTextChange = (itemId, text) => {
    setEditedText(text);
};
```

Actually, you don't need that function at all you can put `setEditedText` directly in `TextInput`.

```js
<TextInput
    style={styles.textText}
    value={editedText}
    onChangeText={setEditedText}
    multiline
/>
```

You also have an error in your beginEdit:

```js
const beginEditItem = (item) => {
    if (!locked) {
        setEditMode(true);
        setEditedText(item.textContent);
        setData((updatedData) =>
            updatedData.map((item) => (item.id === item.id ? { ...item, edited: true } : item))
        );
    }
};
```

You set edited to all items from your data because you use the same variable name for item the item in map shadow the input from the function.

You need:

```js
const beginEditItem = (item) => {
    if (!locked) {
        const id = item.id;
        setEditMode(true);
        setEditedText(item.textContent);
        setData((updatedData) =>
            updatedData.map((item) => (id === item.id ? { ...item, edited: true } : item))
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Now the text reverts instantly to the dummy text stored in memory, without even pressing save or anything, just while typing.

Comment: @infinesse Can you share your code? You deleted your comment that had the wrong code not like in my answer.

Comment: @infinesse No it's not, you have constant `value={item.textContent}` instead of `value={editedText}` [HomeScreen.js#L127](https://github.com/CjDupre/ScreenCacheUI/blob/master/Screens/HomeScreen.js#L127)

Comment: I see. Well when I do that, ALL of the cards display the text as I edit it, then when I "save" it stops the one card from being edited and leaves all the rest editable.

Comment: @infinesse but you only have one InputText element, how is all Cards display text while you edit?

Comment: Line 111 i map over the dummy data stored in serverData.js, so that text input is used 5 times and pulls the text from each object in the data array.

Comment: @infinesse But this is how you created the app, you have dummy data and you edit one Card where you can change that single dummy data into something else. What else do you expect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254203/discussion-between-infinesse-and-jcubic).

Comment: @infinesse you have another bug, see my edit. When you click edit you edit all the cards instead of one.

Comment: ty soo much. im really sorry I took that much of your time

Comment: @infinesse Check this demo, https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/QWJGWKZ?editors=0010 you can write your ReactNative code in the browser so you can test faster and share the working code. Since your problem has nothing to do with ReactNative they are logic errors in your React app.